# New dataframe column based on conditionals of different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty stuck. I'm trying to create a new column based on certain conditions, but the conditions are based on different rows.

Here's an example of my raw data:

| Unique_Identifier | year1 | year2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a |  | 2017 |
| a |  | 2018 |
| a | 2018 |  |
| a | 2019 |  |
| b |  | 2016 |
| b |  | 2018 |
| b | 2016 |  |

What I'm hoping to create is a table that flags for matches between year1 & year2, but based on the Unique_Identifyer. Here's what I mean:

| Unique_Identifier | year1 | year2 | Match? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a |  | 2017 | No |
| a |  | 2018 | Yes |
| a | 2018 |  | Yes |
| a | 2019 |  | No |
| b |  | 2016 | Yes |
| b |  | 2018 | No |
| b | 2016 |  | Yes |

The result doesn't need to be in this format per se since my goal is really to show matching years for each of the unique identifiers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the common years in both the columns and then you can use `np.where`.

**TRY:**

```
import numpy as np

def check_year(x):
    intersect = np.intersect1d(x['year1'].values, x['year2'].values)
    x['Match'] = np.where((x['year1'].isin(intersect) | x['year2'].isin(intersect)),'Yes','No')
    return x
    
df  = df.groupby('Unique_Identifier').apply(check_year)
```

**Output:**

```
  Unique_Identifier  year1  year2 Match
0                 a   <NA>   2017    No
1                 a   <NA>   2018   Yes
2                 a   2018   <NA>   Yes
3                 a   2019   <NA>    No
4                 b   <NA>   2016   Yes
5                 b   <NA>   2018    No
6                 b   2016   <NA>   Yes
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Really appreciate your time and I hope to be able to be as skilled as you one day :) cheers

Comment: I have an added question. Let’s say there was a third year column, let’s call it year3, and I wanted to match year1 and year3 against year2. So if there was a match with year1 and year2, return ‘yes’ under the Match column (like your solution already shows). Additionally though, if there was also a match with year3 and year2, also flag this with a ‘yes’ under the match column. Would I need to create another intersect variable and extend the np.where statement? Thanks again